# Put radio buttons in group

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have 4 different radio buttons that I want to put in two different group. But the problem is I do not want to put buttons vertically or horizontally. I am putting them randomly on layout.

Now how can I apply group on each button?

Comment: This is not a good UI stuff. You are trying to put Radio buttons of same group at different different places. How your user will identify?

Comment: the idea is to put one group on left and other on right, so is there any option to do so..?

Comment: Add groups into table layout having two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
                RadioGroup radioGroup1 = new RadioGroup(context);
                RadioGroup radioGroup2 = new RadioGroup(context);

                RadioButton radioBtn1 = new RadioButton(context);
                RadioButton radioBtn2 = new RadioButton(context);
                RadioButton radioBtn3 = new RadioButton(context);
                RadioButton radioBtn4 = new RadioButton(context);

                radioGroup1.addView(radioBtn1);
                radioGroup1.addView(radioBtn2);
                radioGroup2.addView(radioBtn3);
                radioGroup2.addView(radioBtn4);
```

Comment: then how I handle the location on layout ..?

Answer (score 0):

Use a horizontal `LinearLayout` with 2 equally sized `RadioGroup`s, something like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RadioGroup
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <RadioButton... /> x2
   </RadioGroup> x2
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this seems good idea, but then thr radio buttons would belong parent radio group I guess

Comment: I meant have 2 `RadioGroup`s in the `LinearLayout`, each with 2 `RadioButton`s, identical XML. Just wasn't gonna type it out here